# question with move-spsite and sharepoint IDs

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, move

I am moving about 9 site collections from one database to another. My question is will sharepoint change all the IDs or everything will be intact.

```
move-spsite http://meet.sbc.com/sites/hr -destinationdatabase wss_hr -confirm:$false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run the move command it will preserve all the ids. It is a simple move operation from one db to the other.

I always recommend that you perform a test in lower environment and check after it.

Comment: Perfect. Thank Waqas for the quick reply. I appreciate it.